# Probability: Estimating NoSQL Query Size / COUNT Using Random Samples

Tags: database, count, nosql, probability

I have a very large NoSQL database. Each item in the database is assigned a uniformly distributed random value between 0 and 1. This database is so large that performing a `COUNT` on queries does not yield acceptable performance, but I'd like to use the random values to estimate `COUNT`.

The idea is this:

1. Run a query and order the query by the random value. Random values are indexed, so it's fast.
2. Grab the lowest `N` values, and see how big the largest value is, say `R`.
3. Estimate `COUNT` as `N / R`

The question is two-fold:

1. Is `N / R` the best way to estimate `COUNT`? Maybe it should be `(N+1)/R`? Maybe we could look at the other values (average, variance, etc), and not just the largest value to get a better estimate?
2. What is the error margin on this estimated value of `COUNT`?

*Note: I thought about posting this in the math stack exchange, but given this is for databases, I thought it would be more appropriate here.*

Answer (score 2):

This actually would be better on math or statistics stack exchange.

The reasonable estimate is that if `R` is large and `x` is your order statistic, then `R` is approximately `n / x - 1`.  About 95% of the time the error will be within `2 R / sqrt(n)` of this.  So looking at the 100th element will estimate the right answer to within about 20%.  Looking at the 10,000th element will estimate it to within about 2%.  And the millionth element will get you the right answer to within about 0.2%.

To see this, start with the fact that the [n'th order statistic has a Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) with parameters  `= n` and `β = R + 1 - n`.  Which means that the mean value of the n'th smallest value out of `R` values is `n/(R+1)`.  And its variance is `β / (( + β)^2 ( + β + 1))`.  If we assume that `R` is much larger than `n`, then this is approximately `n R / R^3 = n / R^2`.  Which means that our standard deviation is `sqrt(n) / R`.

If `x` is our order statistic, this means that `(n / x) - 1` is a reasonable estimate of `R`.  And how much is it off by?  Well, we can use the tangent line approximation.  The function `(n / x) - 1` has a derivative of `- n / x^2`  Its derivative at `x = n/(R+1)` is therefore `(R + 1)^2 / n`.  Which for large `R` is roughly `R^2 / n`.  Stick in our standard deviation of `sqrt(n) / R` and we come up with an error proportional to `R / sqrt(n)`.  Since a 95% confidence interval would be 2 standard deviations, you probably will have an error of around `2 R / sqrt(n)`.